# AutoLisp - Prompt User Save As Text File

Tags: lisp, cad, autolisp

I'm trying to write some code to prompt the user on where to save a document. I've run across `getfiled`, which prompts for the user to open an exsisting file, but I'm not finding a command that will show a window as seen below.

[image: DraftSight Save External File]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is a bit more obvious than anticipated. The last argument that can be passed into `getfiled` will change the File Explorer from "Open" to "Save As."

```
;; Opens exsisting file
(getfiled "Title" "test.txt" "" 0)

;; Saves file
(getfiled "Title" "test.txt" "" 1)
```

Reference 1: [help.solidworks.com](https://help.solidworks.com/2022/english/api/draftsightlispreference/html/lisp_function_getfiled.htm)

Reference 2: [help.autodesk.com](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-AutoLISP/files/GUID-AD65DF88-5218-4655-B877-B4D33B9FB6D1.htm#!)

Reference 3: [docs.autodesk.com](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2013/ENU/files/GUID-AD65DF88-5218-4655-B877-B4D33B9FB6D1.htm)

Comment: Out of curiosity. How did you get a resizable window using `(getfiled "Title" "test.txt" "" 0)`?

Comment: I haven't done anything special. I'm simply using DraftSight Professional on a Windows 10 machine. The first time I used the function, the window appeared.

Comment: I thought perhaps it was autocad you were using. Thanks for getting back to me.